Filesystem in arm os
I want to add filesystem in drive to my tiny arm os. I have bootloader:
.global _main
_main:
    ldr x30, =stack_top
    mov sp, x30
    bl notmain
    b .

This bootloader run notmain function from notmain.c file and start infinity loop. So here notmain.c
#include <stdint.h>

#define UART0_BASE 0x09000000
#define UART0_DR (UART0_BASE + 0x00)
#define UART0_FR (UART0_BASE + 0x18)

typedef unsigned long size_t;

void uart_putc(char c){
    volatile uint32_t *UARTFR = (uint32_t *)UART0_FR;
    volatile uint32_t *UARTDR = (uint32_t *)UART0_DR;
    
    while(*UARTFR & (1<<5)){
        
    }
    *UARTDR = c;
}
char uart_getc(){
    volatile uint32_t *UARTFR = (uint32_t *)UART0_FR;
    volatile uint32_t *UARTDR = (uint32_t *)UART0_DR;
    
    while(*UARTFR & (1<<4)){
            
    }
    return *UARTDR & 0xFF;
}
void uart_puts(const char *str){
    while (*str){
        uart_putc(*str++);
    }
}

int my_strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2){
    while (*s1 && (*s1 == *s2)){
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    return (unsigned char)*s1 - (unsigned char)*s2;
}
int my_strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n){
    while (n > 0){
        if(*s1 != *s2){
            return (unsigned char)*s1 - (unsigned char)*s2;
        }
        if (*s1 == '\0'){
            return 0;
        }
        s1++;
        s2++;
        n--;
    }
    return 0;
}
void process_command(const char *cmd, int *debug_mode){
    uart_puts("\r\n");
    
    if(my_strcmp(cmd, "help") == 0){
        uart_puts("Avaible commands: help, echo <message>, debug on, debug off");
    }else if(my_strncmp(cmd, "echo ", 5) == 0){
        uart_puts(cmd + 5);
        uart_putc('\r');
        uart_putc('\n');
    }else if(my_strcmp(cmd, "debug on") == 0){
        *debug_mode = 1;
        uart_puts("Debug mode enabled. \r\n");
    }else if(my_strcmp(cmd, "debug off") == 0){
        *debug_mode = 0;
        uart_puts("Debug mode disable. \r\n");
    }else{
        uart_puts("Unknown command. \r\n");
    }
}
void print_command(const char *cmd, int debug_mode){
    if(debug_mode){
        uart_puts("\r\nReceived command: ");
        uart_puts(cmd);
        uart_putc('\r');
        uart_putc('\n');
    }
}

void notmain(void){
    char c;
    char command[100];
    int index = 0;
    int debug_mode = 0;//0 - debug off, 1 - on
    uart_puts("UART test... \n");
    while(1){
        c = uart_getc();
        if(c == '\r'){
            command[index] = '\0';
            print_command(command, debug_mode);
            process_command(command, &debug_mode);
            index = 0;
        } else if (c == '\b' || c == 127){
            if(index > 0){
                index--;
                uart_puts("\b \b");
            }
        } else{
            if(index < sizeof(command)-1){
                command[index++] = c;
                uart_putc(c);
            }
        }
    }
}


in this code we have simple I/O system.
uart_putc - method which add to console char symbol
uart_puts - method which add to console text (string)
uart_getc - method which get symbols from user's keyboard
my_strcmp/strncmp - methods which i overwrite in this code for not ussing std lib.
process_command - method which handle events from console to do some stuff if this command was printed and btn enter was pressed.
print_command - method for debuging what command was wrote
notmain - main method.
So, i want to add filesystem. In first time i tryed to work localy with ram and i wrote some structs and simple code:
...

#define MAX_FILES 16
#define MAX_NAME_LEGTH 32

typedef unsigned long size_t;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

typedef struct{
    char name [MAX_NAME_LEGTH];
    int is_directory;
} File;
typedef struct{
    File files[MAX_FILES];
    int file_count;
} FileSystem;


FileSystem fs;

...

void my_strcpy(char *dest, const char *src){
    while(*src){
        *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
}

...

void init_fs(){
    fs.file_count = 0;
}
int create_directory(const char *name){
    if(fs.file_count >= MAX_FILES){
        uart_puts("FileSystem is full, cannot create directory.\r\n");
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < fs.file_count; i++){
        if(my_strcmp(fs.files[i].name, name) == 0){
            uart_puts("Directory already exist.\r\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    my_strcpy(fs.files[fs.file_count].name, name);
    fs.files[fs.file_count].is_directory = 1;
    fs.file_count++;
    uart_puts("Directory created. \r\n");
    return 0;
}
void list_directory(){
    uart_puts("Directories:\r\n");
    if(fs.file_count == 0){
        uart_puts("No directories.\r\n");
    }else{
        for (int i = 0; i < fs.file_count; i++){
            if(fs.files[i].is_directory){
                uart_puts(fs.files[i].name);
                uart_putc('\r');
                uart_putc('\n');
            }
        }
    }
}


void process_command(const char *cmd, int *debug_mode){
    uart_puts("\r\n");
    
    if(my_strcmp(cmd, "help") == 0){
        uart_puts("Avaible commands: help, echo <message>, debug on, debug off, mkdir <name>, ls. \r\n");
    }else if(my_strncmp(cmd, "echo ", 5) == 0){
        uart_puts(cmd + 5);
        uart_putc('\r');
        uart_putc('\n');
    }else if(my_strcmp(cmd, "debug on") == 0){
        *debug_mode = 1;
        uart_puts("Debug mode enabled. \r\n");
    }else if(my_strcmp(cmd, "debug off") == 0){
        *debug_mode = 0;
        uart_puts("Debug mode disable. \r\n");
    }else if(my_strncmp(cmd, "mkdir ", 6) == 0){
        create_directory(cmd + 6);
    }else if (my_strcmp(cmd, "ls") == 0){
        list_directory();
    }else{
        uart_puts("Unknown command. \r\n");
    }
}


so i added some defines for making some limiteds for making max amount of files and max length of name.
File: A structure that represents a file or directory, with its name and a flag indicating whether it is a directory.
Filesystem: A structure containing an array of File structures and the current number of files in the file system.
fs: Global variable representing the file system.
init_fs: Initializes the file system by setting the number of files to zero.
create_directory: Creates a new directory with the specified name. Checks that the file system is not full and that the directory does not already exist.
list_directories: List all directories in the file system or inform the user if there are none.
By the way it is only in ram. I read that i need to add VirtFS but i dont found any information about creating filesystem in arm for hard drive, just gag:
int mount_virtfs() {
    uart_puts("Mounting VirtFS...\r\n");
    // simulation for  mount 
    if (/* here is code for mount 9p */ 0 != 0) {
        uart_puts("Failed to mount VirtFS.\r\n");
        return -1;
    }
    uart_puts("VirtFS mounted successfully.\r\n");
    return 0;
}

int create_directory(const char *name) {
    if (fs.file_count >= MAX_FILES) {
        uart_puts("FileSystem is full, cannot create directory.\r\n");
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < fs.file_count; i++) {
        if (my_strcmp(fs.files[i].name, name) == 0) {
            uart_puts("Directory already exists.\r\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    my_strcpy(fs.files[fs.file_count].name, name);
    fs.files[fs.file_count].is_directory = 1;
    fs.file_count++;

    //creating folder usising mkdir (in /mnt/shared)
    uart_puts("Creating directory in VirtFS...\r\n");
    if (/* симуляція команди mkdir в VirtFS */ 0 != 0) {
        uart_puts("Failed to create directory in VirtFS.\r\n");
        return -1;
    }
    uart_puts("Directory created successfully.\r\n");
    return 0;
}


and for virtFS i need to change qemu emulator with using additional args:

qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -cpu cortex-a53 -m 128 -nographic -kernel os.bin -virtfs local,path=/mnt/c/Users/Ukraine/Documents/FlowyOS,mount_tag=shared_fs,security_model=passthrough,id=fs0

So, how i can add file system for hard drives in arm os. Any docs or any examples?
